# How to shuffle/repeat Spotify SDK 0.21.0

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

So I've been pulling my hair out on this one. I can't for the life of me figure out how to enable shuffle or repeat on the `SPTAudioStreamingController`. How do I do it? All I can find is this:

```
let player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
player.playbackState.isShuffling = true
player.playbackState.isRepeating = true
```

Unfortunately these are get-only. Where are the setters?

Answer (score 0):

In beta 25 you can use the method **setShuffle** from the class **SPTAudioStreamingController**

```
// get current state    
let state = player.playbackState.isShuffling
// set shuffle state to opposite state
player.setShuffle(!state, callback: nil)
```